# Why does two dimensional array take only the last two input integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been programming for a while in Java and C++. However, I am trying to learn Python and I am trying to initialize a two-dimensional array in Python. Why does it take only the last two inputs?

I tried everything, but I can't understand why it is not working how it is supposed to be.

```py
   def prog2():
        x = int(input('x> '))
        y = int(input('y> '))
        pole = [[0] * x] * y

        for a in range(x):
            for b in range(y):
                pole[a][b] = int(input('> '))

        print(pole)
    prog2()
```

When I define `x` and `y` as 2, and the following four inputs as 1, 2, 3, 4, 
I expect the output to be [[1, 2], [3, 4]].
However I am getting [[3, 4],[3, 4]]

```py
x> 2
y> 2
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
[[3, 4], [3, 4]]
```

Thank you for your patience and help. :) I am a novice in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
pole = [[0] * x] * y
```

To:

```
pole = [0 for _ in range(x)] * y
```

---

To understand it properly run this code:

```
lists = [[]] * 3
lists[0].append('hi')
print(lists)
```

Ouptut:

```
[['hi'], ['hi'], ['hi']]
```

---

`[0] * x` is evaluated only once and it creates a list. 
`[[0] * x] * y` creates a list containing `y` references of the **same** list.

---

Read more about the behavior in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly).

Comment: Thank you very much! This just seems very strange to me because I am used to typical C++ syntax of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
pole = [[0] * x] * y
```

Sets all of the inner memory addresses equal to each other (each index represents the same object)

Change your initialization:

```
pole = [0 for _ in range(x)] * y
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [copy.deepcopy()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html?highlight=copy#module-copy). When creating the members of the 2-d array you were copying over the same 1-d array object, so the assignment for `pole[0][0]` was assigning to `pole[1][0]` as well, etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import copy
def prog2():
        x = int(input('x> '))
        y = int(input('y> '))
        pole = [[0] * x]
        for i in range(1, y):
            pole.append(copy.deepcopy(pole[0]))
        for a in range(x):
            for b in range(y):
                pole[a][b] = int(input('> '))

        print(pole)
prog2()
```